# How can I refresh a child element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, element, parent

I'm currently using this code inside a functional component :

```
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "700px", overflow: "auto" }}>
      <InfiniteScroll
        pageStart={0}
        loadMore={FetchUpdates}
        hasMore={hasMore}
        loader={
          <ReactLoading type='spin' color='#000000'  />
        }
        useWindow={false}
      >
        <div key={0}>
          {items.map((data) => (
            <Station data={data} func={props.func} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
```

It works fine when `FetchUpdates` method is called. But when I'm refreshing the items element from outside, nothing happens.

```
setItems([]);
```

Any idea would be welcomed.

**Edit :**
I'm using UseCallback to update values from within the parent element.

```
  const UpdateItemsAsync = async () => {
    let items2 = await radioBrowser.Next();
    setItems([...items, ...items2]);
    if (items2.length < 50) {
      setHasMore(false);
    }
    else {
      setHasMore(true);
    }
  };

  const FetchUpdates = useCallback(UpdateItemsAsync, [items]);
```

And a simple call to clear it :

```
  if (!radioBrowser.IsLastSearch(filter, fname)) {
    radioBrowser.configureSearch(filter, fname);
    setItems([]);
    setHasMore(true);
  }
```

**Edit 2**

The full function :

```
function RadioStations(props) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(new Array());
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
  let { filter, fname } = useParams();
  let radioBrowser = new RadioBrowser();

  if (!radioBrowser.IsLastSearch(filter, fname)) {
    radioBrowser.configureSearch(filter, fname);
    setItems([]);
    setHasMore(true);
  }

  const UpdateItemsAsync = async () => {
    let items2 = await radioBrowser.Next();
    setItems([...items, ...items2]);
    if (items2.length < 50) {
      setHasMore(false);
    }
    else {
      setHasMore(true);
    }
  };

  const FetchUpdates = useCallback(UpdateItemsAsync, [items,radioBrowser]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "700px", overflow: "auto" }}>
      <InfiniteScroll
        pageStart={0}
        loadMore={FetchUpdates}
        hasMore={hasMore}
        loader={
          <ReactLoading type='spin' color='#000000'  />
        }
        useWindow={false}
      >
        <div key={0}>
          {items.map((data) => (
            <Station data={data} func={props.func} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you using PureComponent? useMemo or useCallback to refresh the items and it is not updating the state or not passing it with the updated value?

Comment: Your guess is right. I'm using a usecallback with FetchUdaptes. (see edit inmy post)

Comment: Generally whatever variables or functions we use inside `useCallback, useEffect or useMemo` should be added as a dependency. Here the issue is you have items as a dependency but not the function. You should just add function as a part of useCallback itself. Kindly refer the answer.

Comment: The reason to add them as a dependency is to update their memoized value. Here in your useCallback it is always taking the earlier value of your `UpdateItemsAsync` function except when items are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for my problem. Here is my solution:

```
function RadioStations(props) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(new Array());
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
 
  let { filter, fname } = useParams();
  let radioBrowser = new RadioBrowser();

  if (!radioBrowser.IsLastSearch(filter, fname)) {
    console.log('ok');
    radioBrowser.configureSearch(filter, fname);
    setItems([]);
    items.length = 0;
    items.init = 1;
    setHasMore(true);
  }

  const FetchUpdates = useCallback(async () => {
    let items2 = await radioBrowser.Next();
    setItems([...items, ...items2]);
    if (items2.length < 50) {
      setHasMore(false);
    }
    else { 
      setHasMore(true);
    }
  }, [items,radioBrowser]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "700px", overflow: "auto" }}>
       <InfiniteScroll
        pageStart={0}
        loadMore={FetchUpdates}
        hasMore={hasMore || items.init != undefined}
        loader={
          <ReactLoading type='spin' color='#000000'  />
        }
        useWindow={false}
      >
        <div key={0}>
          {items.map((data) => (
            <Station data={data} func={props.func} key={data.stationuuid}/>
          ))}
        </div>
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I may need the entire code structure or working example to answer this in a better way but possibly updating your `useCallback` can solve this.

Generally whatever variables or functions we use inside useCallback, useEffect or useMemo should be added as a dependency.

```js
const FetchUpdates = useCallback(async() => {
  let items2 = await radioBrowser.Next();
  setItems([...items, ...items2]);
  if (items2.length < 50) {
    setHasMore(false);
  } else {
    setHasMore(true);
  }
}, [items, radioBrowser]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've update the function, alas it doesn't work. I've edited my question to give the function.

Comment: In the update code you have shared, have you tried replacing the external function call to `UpdateItemsAsync` to inline function as I have mentioned. 

Or else add UpdateItemsAsync as dependency.

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work. Fortunately, I've found a work around. Thanks for your help, I'm very glad for the time you gave me.